# How do I load data from a txt file into variables in my C program?

Tags: c, file-io

I have a program that has a struct of channels:

```
struct channel
{
   char title[40];
   float gain;
   float offset;
}; 
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct channel channels[8];
}
```

And a text file called `configurationSettings.txt` that holds the information needed to fill up 8 channels:

```
Title1
20
30
Title2
10
0
Title3
34
03
...
```

How would I go about pulling the data from the text file and into their appropriate variables?

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the direction I'm heading so far:

```
FILE *fptr;
if ((fptr=fopen("configurationSettings.txt","r"))==NULL){
   printf("\n\nConfiguration file not found.\n");

  // exit(1); // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL. 
}
while (1) {
    if (fgets(loadedTitle,150, fptr) == NULL) break;
if (fgets(loadedGain,150, fptr) == NULL) break;
if (fgets(loadedOffset,150, fptr) == NULL) break;          
      printf("%s", loadedTitle);
  printf("%s", loadedGain);
  printf("%s", loadedOffset);
      strcpy(channels[i].title, loadedTitle);
  loadedGain == channels[i].gain;
  loadedOffset == channels[i].offset;
}
printf("\n\n%s", channels[i].title);
printf("%f", channels[i].gain);
printf("\n%f", channels[i].offset);
fclose(fptr);
```

Here is the output I get. It's basically just printing everything and storing the last line as the first variable. This is definitely not what I want.

```
Title 1
10
30
Title 2
50
0
Title 3
38
20

20
```

Comment: Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: Also take a look at `fscanf`

Comment: @trenki (to complete your sentence) .... and corresponding error checkings. [Don't get me wrong, really you need to be very careful while using `fscanf()`].

Comment: Ahh sorry guys. I'm new to this site. This community is awesome! Thanks for the tips. I'll look into fscanf.

Comment: Your `channels` array has a fixed size, but your `while` loop is not taking its size into account. Beware of buffer overflows. (Edit: `title` too has a fixed size.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't be writing the code, but can try to help with the algotihm, in general.

1. Open the file.  *Help : [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)*
2. Check for successful opening. *Hint: Return value.*
3. Read a line from the file. Check for the success. *Help : [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) and Return value.*
4. Based on data pattern , tokenize the read line and store into the array.  *Help : [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)*
5. Continue until token is NULL.

---

<sup>Note: At point 4, you need to convert some of the tokens to `float` type. *Help:  [`strtod()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod)*</sup>

---

EDIT:

Appriciate adding the code. Feedback for your code

1. uncomment `// exit(1);`, you really *should* (note, not MUST, you can *skip* also) exit if the `fopen()` failed.
2. `fgets()` reads one *line* at at time. So basically, you need three consecutive `fgets()` to populate one instance of the structure. first `fgets()` will give `title`, second one `gain`, third one `offset`.
3. `fgets()` reads and stores the trailing `\n`. You may want to get rid of that.
4. Use counter to track the structure array member index, too. Your array has only 8  elements here.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Not pedantic, I'd say a MUST. Thank, i'll update. :-)

Comment: I edited my original post. Would you guys mind pointing me in the right direction once again? Thank you

Comment: @ShantCancik No, actually **thank you** for your efforts. See updated answer. :-)

Comment: Thank you Sourav! I have edited the code once again. The errors I'm facing now are that I'm trying to set strings as floats. Is there a simple way to do this? Sorry I started learning how to code this past week. I might be doing some stupid things.

Comment: @ShantCancik No worries, at least you're trying honestly. That's all you need to learn. and for the error, don't use `==`. Did I tell you about [`strtod()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod)?