# Scanning Comma Separated Text File Data into Arrays with C

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, scanf

My goal is to write a code that would scan all the comma seperated data from a text file into an array. To ensure that it was a success, terminal would print out the data in the same fashion.

An example of the data file is

```
XXXX,location,yy,mm,dd,max,min
XXXX,86282,1990,3,1,24.9,18
XXXX,86282,1990,3,2,30.2,15.7
XXXX,86282,1990,3,3,28.2,17.2
XXXX,86282,1990,3,4,28.6,18
XXXX,86282,1990,3,5,25.2,17.5
XXXX,86282,1990,3,6,19.2,15
```

What i have done is this

```
int i = 0;
int a_location[50000];
int a_yy[50000];
int a_mm[50000];
int a_dd[50000];
double a_max[50000];
double a_min[50000];
int location, yy, mm, dd;
double max, min;

while((c=getchar()) != EOF){
    while(scanf("XXXX,%d,%d,%d,%d,%lf,%lf\n",&location, &yy, &mm, &dd, &max, &min) == 6){a_location[i] = location;
    a_yy[i] = yy;
    a_mm[i] = mm;
    a_dd[i] = dd;
    a_max[i] = max;
    a_min[i] = min;

    i+=1;
    }
}

for(i = 1; i < nlines; i++){
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%0.3f,%0.3f\n", a_location[i], a_yy[i], a_mm[i], a_dd[i], a_max[i], a_min[i]);

}
```

the terminal shows this

```
./scan.exe<datafile.txt
0,0,0,0,0.000,0.000
0,0,0,0,0.000,0.000
0,0,0,0,0.000,0.000
0,0,0,0,0.000,0.000
0,0,0,0,0.000,0.000
0,0,0,0,0.000,0.000
```

I would like to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: what is `nlines`?

Comment: [this something helpful?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30887762/2173917)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. But, since you have two undeclared variables in your listed code (`c` and `nlines`), you have obviously not correctly copied-pasted and tested the code in your question, and all bets are off.

Comment: 1. Did you step through your code using a debugger? 2. Obviously you have to skip the first line. 3. Obviously 'nlines' has to be set between the loops (`int nlines =i;`?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: Note that using `getchar()` to read the first character on the line is not a particularly good idea; you need to read that character into the string, in general.  Also, using `scanf()` with a trailing newline in the format string is a minor disaster if you are going to type the data in manually.  And using `scanf()` to process lines is bad; it doesn't care about newlines or white space, for the most part.  You'd do better reading the lines with `fgets()` nd then parsing the result with `sscanf()`.

Comment: Split your problem into smaller parts (opening a file, reading a file line by line, ...) it's very likely that you will find an answer to all that small problems on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You get that result because you are saving the values ​​of the first line that are strings in arrays that are numeric.

You can ignore the first line and then process the following lines, in case the format is maintained.

```
  int i = 0;
  int a_location[50000];
  int a_yy[50000];
  int a_mm[50000];
  int a_dd[50000];
  double a_max[50000];
  double a_min[50000];
  int location, yy, mm, dd;
  double max, min;

  scanf("XXXX,location,yy,mm,dd,max,min\n");
  while(scanf("XXXX,%d,%d,%d,%d,%lf,%lf\n",&location, &yy, &mm, &dd, &max, &min) == 6)
  {
    a_location[i] = location;
    a_yy[i] = yy;
    a_mm[i] = mm;
    a_dd[i] = dd;
    a_max[i] = max;
    a_min[i] = min;
    i++;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < nlines; i++){
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%0.3f,%0.3f\n", a_location[i], a_yy[i], a_mm[i], a_dd[i], a_max[i], a_min[i]);
```

In case of following this method, the index of the for must start in 0.
Regards.

Comment: The `scanf(...) == 6` will take care of the first line. The conversions fail, and scanf returns 0 for the first line, since 0 variables are correctly read. This is not the problem.

Comment: What you say is true, however, this avoids treatment with getchar (). Also, the for() index must begin at 0